# Live Stream from iOS to Wowza

Tags: ios7, streaming, wowza

I am trying to live stream video from iOS to Wowza.

I have downloaded the code from https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos

The values for hostTextField.text is url "rtmp://ip_address/live and streamTextField.text is myStream.

When I hit connect, I get this error

```
<MPIMediaStreamEvent> connectFailedEvent: -7 = fault code = -1 < Input or/and Output Stream is not opened (-1) >
```

Wowza streaming engine is installed on windows 7 laptop.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos (RTMPStreamPublisher) works well

The error below meant, Wowza streaming server was not setup correctly

```
<MPIMediaStreamEvent> connectFailedEvent: -7 = fault code = -1 < Input or/and Output Stream is not opened (-1) >
```

I ditched my personal laptop as Wowza because Wowza had problems resolving local host to ipaddress. I took my free 180 day trial license key and tried out in Amazon Web Service server (EC2 instance), bring your own license method and things worked..

Just want to let folks know that the above error means Wowza streaming server is not receiving the video stream

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get paid library, Visit http://www.realtimelibs.com/

I tried many thing to streaming from ios. you can check for http live streaming if you want to move on http rather than rtmp.

Comment: I was thinking of moving from rtmp to http live streaming. My requirement is for local wi-fi, streaming from iOS device to another laptop or mac. I am looking at documentation of http live streaming. Do you have some examples that I can follo

Comment: Thank You. My use case is little different. I want to allow user to enter a code and take a video from front facing camera and allow the video to be live streamed, The user on the other end will validate code & live streamed video and give his inputs.  I am exploring cocoaHttpServer as well. My use case will be similar to HomeStreamer Lite in apple store + a UIText to accept code at the top that will also be transmitted. Check out this free software in apple store (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/home-streamer-lite-streaming/id892322276?mt=8). I want something similar

Comment: I will see, if I can use web view and your streaming ideas. If it works for my use case or if it works, i will accept.

Comment: You can stream from m3u8 file.